# Cloudfoundry Grails deployment problems - no thread-bound request found

Tags: grails, cloud-foundry

This works locally.  Set up: Grails 2.0.3. Debain Linux.  I've deployed other applications successfully to Cloud Foundry.

Apparently this thing can happen as a consequence of the Spring Security Plugin not being happy with the resources plugin.  Removing the resources plugin doesn't cure this.

This is the problem:

```
Class: java.lang.IllegalStateException
Message: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of
an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? 
If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your 
code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use
RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
```

Adding the org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener and its loader to web.xml and importing them into the page doesn't help either.

There is much about this on the web, but in my case it only happens on Cloud Foundry.

Cloud Foundry runs on Java 1.6, like my machine.  The logs say the same as the quote above, with stack traces identical to what I've found on the web.

Any ideas?  I'm stuck.  I've spent the best of two days on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Adding `compile ":webxml:1.4.1"` to the plugins section of BuildConfig.groovy should fix that. Credit to http://support.cloudfoundry.com/entries/21371626-grails-mongodb-deployment-fails